# Copy Value into byte array in python

Tags: python, arrays, copy, bit, can-bus

I need to copy a value (bigger then a byte) into a byte array for working with CAN messages in python. The value needs to be copied into the array by defining a startbit (NOT byte!) with a supplied length, while the rest of the array stays untouched. The array is 8 bytes long. I am basicly looking for a function which takes an array like this:

```
x = bytearray([0x12,0x12,0x12,0x12,0x12,0x12,0x12,0x12])
```

and copies the value `0x1111` into the array after bit 3, with a fixed length of 6 bits (just an example). If the fixed length is bigger than the value, the rest should be filled with `0x0`.

I would use pointer arithmetics in C to solve this, but how do you do it in python?

Comment: `((8-len(bin(0x12)[2:]))*"0")+bin(0x12)[2:]` give you a binary string from a byte, but need check pattern if got `MSB first` or 'LSB first' definition. Don't forget leading zero if binary length short than eight !

Comment: String, byte,int are same in python (like C). Like this : "A" = (int)65 = (hex)0x41 = (bin)'0b1000001'

Comment: your question is vague, can you add what your expected output should be on 'x' after copying the values 0x1111